# How do I decorate a websocket handler within PerConnectionWebSocketHandler?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-websocket

I am using the PerConnectionWebSocketHandler like so:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
    return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(MyHandler.class));
}
```

where MyHandler is a class implementing the Spring WebSocketHandler interface.

I would like to add an exception handling decorator, that for a single instance can be created like this:

```
new ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator(new MyHandler() );
```

I need the ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator to be wrapped by the PerConnectionWebSocketHandler. When the ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator is on the outside, exceptions  thrown by MyHandler result in the MyHandler.afterConnectionClosed not being called.

How do I combine this with the PerConnectionWebSocketHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebSocketHandler`s can be nested within each other:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
    return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(MyHandler.class));
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler myHandlerDecorator() {
    return new ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator(myHandler());
}
```

This is for case, when you are going to use `BeanFactory` to autowire your target `MyHandler` or via simple way:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandler myHandlerDecorator() {
    return new ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator(
                   new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(MyHandler.class)));
}
```

if not.

In addition you can consider to chain to the `LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator` as well.

**UPDATE**

According to your comment I'd suggest to write your own `ExceptionWebSocketHandler` or just implement all that `ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator` logic in your `MyHandler`. That's because `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler` requires the class with default constructor, even it is delegated to the `this.beanFactory.createBean(this.handlerType)`.

**UPDATE2**

> The difficulty with this approach is that I have more than one handler,

Well, then you can implement your own `PerConnectionExceptionWebSocketHandler`! With the same logic from the `ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator` and `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler`. Or just extend `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler` and override what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator to be wrapped by the PerConnectionWebSocketHandler. When the ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator is on the outside, exceptions  thrown by MyHandler result in the MyHandler.afterConnectionClosed not being called.

Comment: Yes, that is the hack for getting this to work. The difficulty with this approach is that I have more than one handler, and I have to reimplement ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator in each one of them. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.